# Temporary ASP.NET Files Missing

Tags: asp.net

In my asp project throw error at the time running.

Yesterday it works nicely. But today morning it self it gives below message.

```
   Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\bd6e4bde\6cbdacc0\App_global.asax.j5j-uxp-.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Pls Any one tell me why it happnens and how to solve this issue.

Full Error is

> Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to
>   determine why the assembly
>   'file:///C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary
>   ASP.NET Files\root\bd6e4bde\6cbdacc0\App_global.asax.j5j-uxp-.dll'
>   could not be loaded.
>
> === Pre-bind state information === LOG: User = HOME-PC\HOME LOG: Where-ref bind. Location =
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\bd6e4bde\6cbdacc0\App_global.asax.j5j-uxp-.dll LOG: Appbase
>   = file:///G:/Jagadeeswaran/Test Project/MobileApp/MobileApp/MobileApp/ LOG: Initial PrivatePath = G:\Jagadeeswaran\Test
>   Project\MobileApp\MobileApp\MobileApp\bin Calling assembly :
>   (Unknown).
>   === LOG: This bind starts in LoadFrom load context. WRN: Native image will not be probed in LoadFrom context. Native image will only be
>   probed in default load context, like with Assembly.Load(). LOG: Using
>   application configuration file: G:\Jagadeeswaran\Test
>   Project\MobileApp\MobileApp\MobileApp\web.config LOG: Using host
>   configuration file:  LOG: Using machine configuration file from
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary
>   ASP.NET Files/root/bd6e4bde/6cbdacc0/App_global.asax.j5j-uxp-.dll.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> ```
> [FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary
> ```
>
> ASP.NET Files\root\bd6e4bde\6cbdacc0\App_global.asax.j5j-uxp-.dll' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
>          System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly
>   locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound,
>   Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
>          System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly
>   locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound,
>   Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +39
>          System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName
>   assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark,
>   Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +132
>          System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity) +28
>          System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerResults.get_CompiledAssembly() +93
>          System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.CreateBuildResult(CompilerResults
>   results) +65
>          System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.GetBuildResult(CompilerResults
>   results) +16
>          System.Web.Compilation.ApplicationBuildProvider.GetGlobalAsaxBuildResult(Boolean
>   isPrecompiledApp) +8999743
>          System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileGlobalAsax() +50
>          System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled() +265
>
> ```
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary
> ```
>
> ASP.NET Files\root\bd6e4bde\6cbdacc0\App_global.asax.j5j-uxp-.dll' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
>          System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ReportTopLevelCompilationException()
>   +62
>          System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled() +421
>          System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallAppInitializeMethod() +31
>          System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager
>   appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory
>   configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters,
>   PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +691
>
> ```
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary
> ```
>
> ASP.NET Files\root\bd6e4bde\6cbdacc0\App_global.asax.j5j-uxp-.dll' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
>          System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +8972180
>          System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +97
>          System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr) +258

So I re install the Vs 2010 also But Same error repeat.

Please Help me to solve this issue.

Comment: I don't think reinstalling Visual Studio will solve it, Try reinstalling .Net framework 4, and then publish your site to IIS again and make sure it is using Framework 4 under IIS

Comment: the vs 2010 include the framework.

Comment: It work yesterday. But not now Why?. I didn't change anything.

Comment: re installing Framework is also not help me.

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have disabled `CopyLocal` in Visual Studio project and enable it. It seems some assembly dependencies are not copied to temp folder and you get the run-time binding error.

Comment: Where can i find this CopyLocal in Vs?

Comment: in properties window of any dependency of your project.

Comment: Are You Telling About "Copy to Output Dir" ?. I cant find CopyLocal. Do you have any picture or image.

Comment: Yes. Sorry I'm a hobby programmer.